# Using Keras Model as a Broadcast variable with Apache Spark & Elephas

Tags: apache-spark, keras, broadcast

I have a keras model with pretrained weights [h5df] of about 700mb. I would like to use it with Apache Spark as a broadcast variable. 
1. This does not seem to be possible as the keras model itself is not spark aware and not serializable. 
2. When googled it a little, I have found Elephas library that does the work. So tried wrapping up the Keras pretrained model in ElephasTransformer. This is throwing multiple errors as ( I use python 2.7 ). For example in the file ml_model.py of Elephas, "from pyspark.ml.util import keyword_only" , the import is not available. Even when I try to comment this out and make appropriate modifications in the code, it seems to be unable to handle the broadcasting of the keras model as it throws a tensor error in one of the dense layers.

How to use a pretrained keras model as a broadcast variable in apache spark ?

Comment: I successfully shared across a 900MB data inside a broadcast variable. I guess, the only requirement for an object to be a broadcast variable, is it should be serializable. It can be easily done inside Java, not so sure about python. Is it possible to share some code that we can look into?

Comment: Have you found a solution for it?

Answer (score 7):

I'd distribute the models using `SparkFiles`

```
spark.sparkContext.addFile("model_file.h5")
```

and load locally:

```
from pyspark import SparkFiles
from keras.models import load_model

def f(it):
    path = SparkFiles.get("mode_file.h5")
    model =  load.model(path)

    for i in it:
        yield ... # Do something


rdd.mapPartitions(f)
```

Comment: Have you implemented this approach in practice? I'm curious if it worked well for you. By the way, you imported `load_model` but later called `load.model()`.

Comment: This is the only way that worked for me. Serialization of keras models with custom layers is not supported by any library (to the point that I have searched) so I had to follow this solution.

Answer (score 0):

In Elephas, the way I approached this problem was making the weights a broadcast variable, providing the yaml string as an argument to the mapper function, and just create the model inside the mapper function using the loaded yaml file and the weights - something to the effect of:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import model_from_yaml

weights = rdd.context.broadcast(model.get_weights())

def mapper_function(yaml_file, ...):
    model = model_from_yaml(yaml_file)
    model.set_weights(weights.value)
```